# Viewing sharepoint site, document libraries, attachments externally

Tags: document-library

I would like to show someone (like admins) how they can view, manage (move or create new contents) in a sharepoint site. Basically the content within document library is so huge that out-of-box feature of 'open in explorer' window is not working well.

I was wondering if there is anything available that will expose sharepoint site and its document libraries that can be used a file management tool.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe no additional tool is neccessary, You can connect your library like web folder (web dav), just open your network place and add new connection similar to this one:

"\portal.domain@SSL\site-collection\site\library"

or

"https:\portal.domain\site-collection\site\library"

Comment: I showed that but they are looking for tool where they get complete snapshot of all the document libraries in that site and when they click within each document library, it shows (and allows them to copy/create/delete files,folders).

Comment: OK, what about the "Site Content and Structure" tool from Site Administration? Can they have rights for it ? See this link http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/work-with-site-content-and-structure-HA010131723.aspx (article for 2007, but idea is the same for 2010)

Comment: I can't find that option. Is it only in Moss or sharepoint server 2010?

Comment: MOSS 2007, SP server 2010 I think

Comment: MOSS = 2007, SP2010 = 2010, so either one

Comment: I am using sharepoint foundation 2010 (and also WSS 3.0)

Comment: Both mentioned I think, but someone more experienced than me can answer this question. But maybe you need to activate Publishing feature on site first

Comment: Content and Structure is an Publishing Infrastructure feature, so it's not available in WSS or Foudations.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SharePoint Designer to manage your Content. SharePoint Designer is available for SharePoint 2007 (WSS 3.0) and 2010 (Foundation). You can install both versions on the same client. Both versions are free.

Comment: That's a really interesting idea...never thought of SPD for that use case. My concern would be how well it would perform managing a large list/library. My experience with SPD is it doesn't perform well period...I imagine trying to manage a "huge" document library with it would be painfully slow, but that's just an assumption. Either way, interesting idea...maybe you should test it out with large doc lib and publish a blog post.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SP2010, then maybe SharePoint Workspace 2010 is an option. This tool (included in Office 2010) allows you to take entire site collection or just a subset, offline. Any editting done on files while offline will get synced the next time the user connects.

Comment: Anything for Wss 3.0 ?

Comment: FYI, Workspace is only included with the Professional version of Office 2010, but it is a good option if you're using SP2010

Answer (score 0):

The "open in explorer" feature doesn't perform well if you have a lot of items in the root of the doc lib or in any sub folder you open in the view.

I'm not aware of any free stuff out there that will handle this requirement, although I'm sure you could find something if you look hard enough.

You might want to look at Colligo Contributor File Manager: http://www.colligo.com/products/sharepoint/contributor_file_manager.asp

There may be other stuff out there but this is the only one I've personally used in the past.